# ubuntu : can't cd to /var/www despite being in www-data group

Tags: apache, ubuntu, permissions

Am trying to set up a web site in an apache2 www folder on ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
Installed the LAMP as per the manual: sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
Then have done:

```
$ usermod -g www-data myuser
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www 
$ sudo chmod -R go-rwx /var/www
$ sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
$ sudo chmod -R o+r /var/www
```

So, was going to copy files into www.. 
But when I (as myuser) try to

```
$ cd /var/www
```

I get :

```
-bash: cd: /var/www: Permission denied
```

Not sure what to do now...myuser is in the www-data group...
But, one thing that might not be right is that my user is only in sudo and www-data... should it be in users as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add executable permissions to a folder in order to be able to cd into it.

So, you should have done:

```
$ sudo chmod -R g+rwx /var/www
```

Comment: Arghh!! I should have known that!! Thanks so much